# Mac OS X libraries path setup

Tags: macos, osx-lion, path

In OSX, by default, (apple) libs and components live in /usr.

Since I use MacPorts and compile my own modules, I have the following path setup:

```
/usr -> default Apple
/usr/local -> My own compiled
/opt/local -> MacPorts
```

In my `.bash_profile` I have the following PATH variable set:

```
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

However, the PATH variable is not available for all Users and services.

---

**Q. Is this setup recommended? What problems might arise with this?**

.

Q. I'm Running the Default Apache 2 installation with a compiled version of PHP 5.4.8. **Where is the best place to set the PATH variable?** Keep it in bash_profile? Or do I need to use ~/.launchd.conf or /etc/.launchd.conf so that Apache sees the new PATH var?

---

**NOTE:**

Up until recently, every time I needed to install or update a new library, I would compile and replace the ones provided by apple. Unfortunately, that's a path that ultimately leads to insanity, as I found out after a system update crashed my computer completely, forcing me to factory format.